# Return to the CLI main menu when an option has been selected

Tags: c#, input, io, command-line-interface, user-input

#### Introductions - Explanation of the application

I am currently developing a console application that includes a CLI menu.

The application allows the user to access various other menus by entering a number.

#### Problem - Back to the CLI main menu

If the user is in another menu, I want the user to return to the main menu by entering number 5.

But I do not know how to do this programmatically.

#### Source Code

```
 Console.WriteLine(@"



                ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                │                                                                         │
                │  Test                                                                   │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │    1 - Test                                                             │
                │    2 - Test                                                             │
                │    3 - Test                                                             │
                │    4 - Test                                                             │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


");

         int _select = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (_select == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(@"



                ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                │                                                                         │
                │  Test                                                                   │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │    1 - Test                                                             │
                │    2 - Test                                                             │
                │    3 - Test                                                             │
                │    4 - Test                                                             │
                │                                                                         │
                │    5 - Exit                                                             │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


");
```

Comment: A sensible way might be to have a method which prints the menu and waits for input, then returns the selected option. Then you can call this method whenever you need to display the menu. Also, you probably need a loop round the main part of your program so it never exits until the user selects the relevant option. I'd be astonished if you can't find examples of a menu-based console program online already which you could get ideas from. What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

To create an **effective mechanism** for the application, we integrate **functions** and **classes**.

**Classes** and **methods** can be integrated in many ways to solve the problem in many **different** ways.

---

- New class and functions

  ```
   public class Menu
    {
        private static int _select;

        public static void RootMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"



                ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                │                                                                         │
                │  Application name                                                       │
                │                                                                         │
                │  Description of the application                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │    1 - Menu                                                             │
                │    1 - Menu                                                             │
                │    2 - Menu                                                             │
                │    3 - Menu                                                             │                                                    
                │                                                                         │
                │    5 - Exit                                                             │
                │                                                                         │
                └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ ");
  ```

---

- User input that defines which menu to display

  ```
          _select = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (_select == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine(@"



                ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                │                                                                         │
                │   1 - Menu                                                              │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │        1 - Option                                                       │   
                │                                                                         │
                │        2 - Option                                                       │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │                                                                         │
                │    5 - Exit                                                             │
                │                                                                         │
                └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ ");
  ```

---

- User input that executes the function

  ```
          _select = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (_select == 5)
                {
                    ReturnRootMenu();
                }


            }
  ```

---

- Function that displays the main menu when the function is executed in classes or methods

  ```
    public static void ReturnRootMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        RootMenu();


    }
  ```

---

[image: GIF of the application]

Comment: Thank you very much. You have answered very professionally. I have one last question.

Do you have a definition of what classes are exactly?

Comment: Classes are complex data types. Classes are complex because they can store more data than primitive data types.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)